# pass multiple column values from c# into stored procedure made in sql already

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have successfully created my stored procedure in sql server which takes in 3 parameters-- TABLE_NAME , ATTR_NAMES and ATTR_VALUES.

Example

```
exec Insert 'name,descr','''abc'',''cde''','tableEmployee'
```

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert] 
(
    @table_name varchar(50), 
    @attr_names varchar(50),
    @attr_values varchar(50)
)
AS 
    insert into @table_name (col1, col2, col3) 
    values (val1, val2, val3)
```

My query is how to call this procedure from c# code !!

How to pass the parameters in the same way like

```
'name,descr','''abc'',''cde''','tableEmployee'
```

in one go into the stored procedure in SQL Server?

please help ... :((!!!

Comment: Parameters cannot be used in this way for table or column names.

Comment: you have to use dynamic sql, and also avoid using keyword as sp name

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like this:

```
using(var cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand())
{ 
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
   cmd.CommandText = "Insert";

   var tblName = cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("table_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
   var attr_names = cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("attr_names", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
   var attr_values = cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("attr_values", SqlDbType.NVarChar));

   tblName.Value = "tableEmployee";
   attr_names.Value = "name,descr";
   attr_values.Value = "'abc','cde'";

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

However you have made several mistakes in your stored procedure. And using 'Insert' as a name for the stored procedure is quite unfortunate because it is a reserved keyword in SQL.

As others have pointed out in comments, the following is not valid:

```
insert into @table_name (col1,col2,col3) values (val1,val2,val3)
```

In the above, `@table_name` would refer to a local table variable (which you haven't defined) and `val1,val2,val3` will also produce and error since you have not really defined those either.

Comment: Parameters cannot be used for table or column names.

Comment: @Steve - that's not what the OP is asking. His question was how to call his stored proc from C#

Comment: @mike- my stored procedure works fine. i have  shortened it here. My aim is to take user inputs that may be multiple and definite ..and  calling stored procedure in c# to insert into my table given by user in parameters

Comment: @user3228318 - you have to be more specific then. what does your stored proc look like exaclty? and what do you want your input to look like?

Comment: @user3228318 Your stored procedure works fine? I really have many doubts about this, not to mention the possibility to create a stored procedure with that text. `You should get _Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertTest, Line xxx Must declare the table variable "@table_name".`